# Error on accessing Output Variable in beanshell preprocessor in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, jmeter-5.0

I am unable to print 'Output Variable' value of foreach Controller in Beanshell Pre/Post-processor in Jmeter.

```
log.info("inside hash"+ ${current_file} ); //current_file is the Output variable name defined in foreach controller and has the value of current file path.
File file=new File(${current_file});
byte[] content = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);
```

Whenever I execute the tests, I get this error:

2021-12-15 19:58:25,208 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils; import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileSe . . . '' Encountered "( "inside hash" + C :" at line 4, column 9.

Can anyone help me fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Don't inline [JMeter functions or variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in form of `${current_file}`, use **vars** shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance instead

   Something like:

   ```
   String current_file = vars.get("current_file");
   log.info("inside hash"+ current_file );
   File file=new File(current_file);
   ```
2. [Don't use Beanshell](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead), since JMeter 3.1 it's [recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting, there is a chance that your code will just start working after switching to Groovy or at least you will get more informative errors.

Comment: This tweak worked right away! Thanks.